# How to query history commits of certain branch with GraphQL

Tags: graphql, gitlab

I'm trying to query the commit history of a project's repository of certain branch with GraphQL, is this possible? I could not find a related example in the GitLab docs, or do I have to use the REST API?

I can only query lastCommit, how to query list of commits

```
{
  project(fullPath:"group-name/project-name"){
    repository{
      tree{
        lastCommit{
          title
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```